# Multiple actions for multiple arrays in list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I would like to substitute the '1's on an array `nparray1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])` by the values on another array `nparray2 = np.array([8,7,4])`, to produce `nparray1 = np.array([8, 7, 0, 0, 4])`.

I was hoping to do this as efficiently as possible, hence I thought using a list comprehension would be the best alternative, however, I am unable to find a way to do this. The alternative for loop would look like:

```
nparray1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
nparray2 = np.array([8,7,4])

for i in range(len(nparray1)):
    if nparray1[i]==True:
        nparray1[i] = nparray2[0]
        nparray2    = nparray2[1:]
```

Comment: If `nparray2 = np.array([8,7,4,4])` or `nparray1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])`

Comment: is the length of `nparray2` guaranteed to equal the length of `nparray1[nparray1 == 1]`?

Comment: A list comprehension is an alternative to a `for` loop with list append; and even there it offers only a modest speed gain.  It isn't intended for complex in-place actions; it returns a new list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
nparray1[nparray1 == 1] = nparray2
print(nparray1)

# Output
array([8, 7, 0, 0, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, I think you can also keep track of an idx variable which you only increment when you see a 1 in the first numpy array.

```
nparray1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
nparray2 = np.array([8,7,4])

idx = 0;
for i in range(len(nparray1)):
    if nparray1[i] == 1: 
        nparray1[i] = nparray1[i] * nparray2[idx]
        idx+=1

print(nparray1)
```

or alternatively, via the use of `iter()`:

```py
nparray1 = numpy.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
nparray2 = iter(numpy.array([8,7,4]))

for i in range(len(nparray1)):
    if nparray1[i]== 1:
        nparray1[i] = next(nparray2)

print(nparray1)
```

Comment: would it be cleaner to just turn nparray2 into an `iter()` and use `next()`?

Comment: May you elaborate a bit on the approach? I am not very familiar this part of Python so I am not able to infer what to do after converting into an `iter()`. Definitely would not be surprised if there is cleaner way though

Comment: I'll edit the answer and if you don't like it, feel free to revert

Comment: Oh ok, got it now, we used `iter()` and `next()` to avoid initializing a new variable.